# No Start, No Crank Issue

Tags: starter, boat, no-crank-no-start

I have a Volvo Penta 4.3gxi-g with a no start, no crank condition.

This started with an intermittent no start, no crank condition. It is impossible to get to the starter motor itself due to how the boat engine compartment is set up. So, I was looking for an indirect way to do the test. Now with the results, I just want to be sure it is the start/solenoid as it requires pulling the engine to change the starter.

Two days ago, everything was running fine. Started the motor, ran it, shut it down. Now, consistent no start, no crank.

I tested the ignition switch and have 12.4 volts on the run circuit and 12.4 volts on the start circuit (when key turned to start).

Using a power probe, I found the right relay in the engine bay (no diagram available) using the power probe and finding the one relay that powered up when the key was turned to start. On that socket, reading was 12.4 volts.

With the power probe, put 12 volts to the 87 pin on the relay socket. This should simulate close of the relay and power to the solenoid.

I get a voltage drop of 10.4 volts (readout on the power probe) but no solenoid sound, etc.

So, I'm deducing it is the starter motor, or more likely the solenoid.

I would appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: since you're using a power probe assuming you're on the correct relay. is the circuit to the solenoid grounded or is it an open circuit (e.g. 0.0 on the display)? can you get at the wiring and use a piercing probe to power the solenoid?